# Как сделать отдинаковый отступ между колонками и краем экрана в Bootstrap?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap4

Хочу сделать отступ между колонками. Чтобы он был таким же по ширине, как отступы от краёв экрана до колонок. Это в случае когда колонки помещаются по ширине экрана.

После того, как экран становится уже и они перестроятся одна под одной, такой же по ширине отступ должен быть до края экрана до столбца.

Исходное состояние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным отметил одинаковые по длине margin.

Сделал экран Уже.
Столбцы перестроились один под одним.
При этом у первого отступ справа больше, чем слева (отметил синим).

После перестроения:

[image: После перестроения]

Второй блок опустился под первый и у него по ширине растянулось нормально.

Моя вёрстка на Bootstrap 4 (без верхнего блока, только столбцы):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row no-gutters bd-light">
  <section class="col bg-white shadow mb-3 mr-3">
  col-1
  </section>

  <section class="col bg-white shadow mb-3">
  col-2
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol: так это Вам задание - подключите bootstrap, напишите стили :)

Comment: Это Bootstrap 4, я поэтому css и не указывал. Он стандартный.

Comment: Подключил Boostrap

Comment: если в одном случае у вас `mr-3` написан, а в другом нет, то чего удивляетесь? используйте `mr-xx-3` классы в зависимости от того, как перестраивается сетка в данном размере

Comment: В первом случае я ставлю mr-3 чтобы был отступ между столбцами, когда они оба влазят по ширине.

Но после перестроения он мне уже не нужен.

Столбцы сейчас перестраиваются сами без брейкпоинтов.

Реально ли такую задачку решить?